# How to extract a word that can be in any column

Tags: excel, formula

I have this table with multiple characteristics and i need to extract only one, for example the "Capacity" that can be somewhere in this sample range, and match it with its ID.

[image]

I need it do return the info like this.

[image: 2]]

I tried with INDEX, MATCH but it didn't work.

Comment: What do you mean by "match it with its ID" ?  What exactly do you need to do?

Comment: @TimWilliams I updated the post, I think it's more clear now

Comment: If an id has no "Capacity" what should be returned?

Comment: How do we recognize the data is a Capacity? Is there a label, a format or anything else to recognize it? Do you need a formula-based solution or are you familiar/accept VBA solution too? If VBA is fine, do you prefear a sub or a function?

Answer (score 1):

A rudimentary formula solution:

```
=INDEX($B$2:$F$6,MATCH(H2,$A$2:$A$6,0),MATCH(IF(ISNUMBER(FIND("Cap",B2)),B2,IF(ISNUMBER(FIND("Capacity",C2)),C2,IF(ISNUMBER(FIND("Capacity",D2)),D2,IF(ISNUMBER(FIND("Capacity",E2)),E2,IF(ISNUMBER(FIND("Capacity",F2)),F2))))),$B2:$F2,0))
```

[image: Formula applied]

EDIT: Updated to add INDEX/MATCH as I now understand your inquiry.

Comment: I tried and it returned "false". The cell should only have "Capacity"? or if it's "Capacity: 15 oz", it'll work?

Comment: I tried it. It should find any cell that contains "Capacity" including "Capacity: 15oz".
FIND finds the text and returns a number representing the position of the first character in the string it is searching.